# eventListeners are being multiplied when clicked on

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have my eventListeners set in a function, the removeEventListener is being called right after the function of my button is executed.

I know that the other listeners will still be present so how can I remove all of them once one has been triggered?

```
function listeners() {

    function good() {
        eventGood();
        this.removeEventListener("click", good);
    }

    function mild() {
        eventMild();
        this.removeEventListener("click", mild);
    }

    function bad() {
        eventBad();
        this.removeEventListener("click", bad);
    }

    function eventGood() {
        x = 1;
    }

    function eventMild() {
        x = 2;
    }

    function eventBad() {
        x = 3;
        }

    answerOne.addEventListener("click", good);
    answerTwo.addEventListener("click", mild);
    answerThree.addEventListener("click", bad);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by using .onclick.

function listeners() {

```
answerOne.onclick = function(){
    x = 1;

}

answerTwo.onclick = function(){
    x = 2;

}

answerThree.onclick = function(){
    x = 3;

}
```

}